# Helm values string to boolean

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm, helm3

new to helm and templating. I have a helm value file which needs to refer the value from another common values file.

```
enabled:  "{{ .Values.common.service.enabled }}"
```

and the output i expect is

`enabled: false`
but i always get with the quotes

`enabled: "false"`

The common values file

```
service:
  enabled : "false"
```

Have tried  `toYaml` but still same

````
enabled:  "{{ .Values.common.service.enabled | toYaml }}"
```
`
````

Answer (score 1):

You're receving the quotes because you wrote the quote in the declaration of the component. Instead, the component definition yaml is:

```
enabled: {{ .Values.common.service.enabled }}
```

and the values.yaml:

```
common:
  service:
    enabled: false
```

Comment: thanks .. unfortunately the parent component is a generated file where we use envsubst , where i have tried  `"enabled: ${SERVICE:-false}"` and it always gives me default value with quoted string `"false"`

Comment: please send some code that is possible to check otherwise is difficult to understand the problem